# What is impeding current when voltage is stepped up in a transformer?

Tags: current, transformer, impedance, physics

What is physically impeding electric current when a transformer steps up voltage? Is there some EM field along the conductor impeding electron movement?

FYI, I'm not asking about losses or leakage. (assuming ideal transformer) I'm trying to get an electromagnetic explanation of how increasing turns on the secondary winding exchanges current for voltage.

Thank you.

Comment: you cannot create power from nothing ... if voltage goes up, then current has to go down and vice versa

Comment: Do you understand what opposes current when you apply voltage to an inductor? If you say something about how you model that scenario in your mind, we might be able to build on that to explain a transformer.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is 'impeding the current' in a step-up transformer. If you drive a low resistance load on the output, it will draw a large current.

The action of a good transformer is to tend to equalise the Ampere.Turns product in the primary and secondary, in an ideal transformer they are equal.

The primary of a step-up transformer will have fewer turns than the secondary, so whatever current the secondary is providing, a correspondingly larger current will be drawn by the primary.

Ultimately, if you short circuit the secondary, then the current will be limited by the resistance of the windings (both primary and secondary, and connecting leads), the output impedance of the source, and in a non-ideal transformer its leakage reactance (the inability to have an infinite permeability core, or the windings in physically the same space rather than simply close). However, because of the ratio of turns, the secondary current will still be smaller than the primary current by approximately that ratio.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the transformer, not including losses, is that Power out = Power in.
Or said another way, Primary power = Secondary power.

If you have a simple 2 winding, 2:1 Step Up transformer, and drive the Primary with 100 VAC, then you will measure 200 VAC as the Secondary voltage.

Now add a load to the Secondary. Let's make it simple and make it 200 ohms.

The Secondary current will be: 200V/200 ohm = 1 amp.

Now, what is the primary current?

Since the turns ratio is:  2,  then the Primary current will be 2.0 amp.

Power Pri  =  Power Sec
100v x 2 amps  =  200v x 1 amp  =  200 watts

The Secondary current is determined by the Secondary voltage and Secondary load.

As you increase the the load on the Secondary (lower the resistance) then the current in the Secondary and Primary both increase, and they will always be in the 2:1 ratio.

Hope this helps.

All the Best.